# Simple folder sharing system similar to AMMYY

Tags: windows, file-synchronization

I'm trying to implement a file sharing system over the web in my company. There are a lot of cloud solutions or folder sharing programs.

Unfortunately:
The first ones are expensive for the amount of data we have;
And the second require us to configure our router, something we can't do (ex: Syncthing).

So I was looking for a solution that worked liked AMMYY, meaning:
Direct access to a computer's folder;
No port configuration;
No IP specification.

I Know the security risks involved. It's a dangerous system because anyone can access our files. But this data isn't sensitive information, this method is simply to facilitate the company's workflow...

I've searched for alternatives to Syncthing at alternativeto.net but can't seem to find a good solution...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Can work in any OS, but files have to be acessible from windows OS.
P.P.S.: Preferably open-source.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a pretty good experience with [bittorrent sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) - its almost zero configuration -You set up a client, generate and pass a numeric key from the system which you're using as the source to the system(s) you're sending files to. You have the option of read-write access and read only access. You can revoke access to the files simply by changing the key.

It runs on most common systems - windows, or linux x86, Arm (I had a copy running on a raspberry pi) or even MIPS based NASes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying Retro Share, but I'll try that one too.

Comment: Sorry for double post... but this bittorrent sync automatically downloads? or can I just have access to that folder?

Comment: The former, unless you're using the mobile client

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at croc! https://github.com/schollz/croc

It syncs just with a password from pc2pc